# Resolve dependencies on unit testing xUnit

Tags: c#, .net, razor, xunit, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a service that converts a razor view into string and I want to unit test it. Problem is that it has some dependencies in the constructor (IRazorViewEngine, ITempDataProvider, IServiceProvider) which are injected via dependency injection in the normal startup class, but for testing I don't know how can I supply these dependencies.

The method I want to test is "RenderToStringAsync()"

```
    public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider
        , IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.GetView("~/", viewName, false);

            if (viewResult.View == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
            }

            var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
            {
                Model = model
            };

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                viewResult.View,
                viewDictionary,
                new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on how can I provide these dependencies ? Thanks

Comment: Have a look into Moq - this will help you mock out the dependencies and set them up against the test: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992825/the-right-way-to-use-moq-setup-and-returns

Comment: Yes, for unit test, you need to mock the dependencies. For integration testing, you can utilize the test server in ASP.NET Core to provide the service collection. However, this would be a clear cut case where you should be unit testing this functionality.

Comment: maybe first you might want to read about unit test vs an integration test and why this shouldn't be called a service, instead write integration tests against your controllers and separate out your business logic from (to add unit test against) rendering logic